# TinyMVC PDO layer raising error on database query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, autoloader, tinymvc

When I use the built in PDO layer in TinyMVC to request records from a table, it returns the following error:

```
Array
Error: 0
Message: Unknown file 'register_view.php'
File:{redacted}tinymvc\sysfiles\plugins\tinymvc_view.php
Line: 125
```

When I however try just returning the same variable without a connection it displays it fine. The error it is raising is in the view layer because it cannot get the parameter passed to it. However I see no reason why it is doing that considering the query is running ok.

Here is the code from the view method:

```
<body>
<h1>Hello <?=$fname?></h1>
<p>Hello World</p>
```

And the code from the controller:

```
function index(){
    $this->load->model('User_Model','user');
    $this->view->assign('title','Manage your Peacock account');
    $this->view->assign('fname', $this->user->fname());
    $this->view->display('user_view');
}
```

Finally the code from the model:

```
public function __get($property) {
    if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
        /**
         * Retrieve the data from the database
         */
        $this->$property = $this->db->query_one('select '.$this->getTable($property).' from users where id=?',array('1'));
        return $this->$property;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Isn't the error *Unknown file 'register_view.php'*? Seems more like an incorrect file path issue or something similar

Comment: It would seem so.however I have included the file directly and still get the same error.the error only occurs when I am using the database object

Comment: I'd start at line 125 of `tinymvc\sysfiles\plugins\tinymvc_view.php` and work backwards from there, preferably using a debugger

Answer (score 0):

TinyMVC has the unfortunate trait of declaring an "Unknown file" error whenever a view with a fatal error is "display"ed. The reason is simple: the include code for the view is in /tinymvc/sysfiles/plugins/tinymvc_view.php in the last function - "_view()" in a "try-catch" block:

```
 try {
  include($_tmvc_filepath);
 } catch (Exception $e) {
  throw new Exception("Unknown file '$_tmvc_filepath'");      
 }
```

so ANY fatal error raised by the view automatically throws the "Unknown file" error.
If you want to see the real error, comment all the above lines and add the line:

```
require($_tmvc_filepath);
```

instead. This will anyways raise a fatal error if the file really isn't found, and will show you the real error that is in the view.